# @ operator in VBA formula: Runtime 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When my colleague runs the following line of code

```vb
Range("D4:D" & WorkingRowCount).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(@C1,'Brand lookup'!C1:C3,3,0),""Error"")"
```

it results in

> runtime error 1004

For me it works.

`WorkingRowCount` is a count of the rows with data in the sheet, and is declared as a Long variable type:

```vb
Dim WorkingRowCount As Long
WorkingRowCount = Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: your formula includes the implicit intersection operator @, which is valid for Excel 365 only.  Does your colleague have Excel 365?

Comment: Chris Neilsen, you're absolutely right, she had an issue with her computer whereby she hadn't had the relevant excel updates and so it was a compatibility issue relating to the @ operator, which has now been resolved.
Thank you for your help.